# Wildcards and query semantics in JsonPointer with Jackson

Tags: jackson, jsonpointer

Jackson provides JsonPointer. However, I want to do something like that what https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath can provide. How do I describe this in JsonPointer?:

```
$.store.book[?(@.price < 10)]
```

somethink like:

```
JsonPointer p = JsonPointer.compile("/store/book[????]");
```

Answer (score 0):

JsonPath and [JsonPointer](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6901) serve different purposes. You won't be able to apply a pattern like above. You can read the [Evaluation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6901#section-4) section to learn more about how JsonPointers work.